# How to get a first and last value of one column based on another column values

Tags: sql, python-3.x, hiveql

I have a data looks like below.

```
TS                         Col
2019-01-04T01:49:00.000Z    B
2019-01-04T01:50:00.000Z    B
2019-01-04T01:51:00.000Z    B
2019-01-04T01:52:00.000Z    A
2019-01-04T01:53:00.000Z    A
2019-01-04T01:54:00.000Z    A
2019-01-04T01:55:00.000Z    A
2019-01-04T01:56:00.000Z    C
2019-01-04T01:57:00.000Z    C
2019-01-04T01:58:00.000Z    B
2019-01-04T01:59:00.000Z    B
2019-01-04T02:00:00.000Z    B
```

I want to extract the value of the first and last "TS" column based on each "Col" column values (A, B, and C) when it changes.
The expected output should be as follows

```
start_ts                     end_ts
2019-01-04T01:49:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:51:00.000Z
2019-01-04T01:52:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:55:00.000Z
2019-01-04T01:56:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:57:00.000Z
2019-01-04T01:58:00.000Z    2019-01-04T02:00:00.000Z
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  This version is probably best addressed using the difference of row numbers:

```
select col, min(ts), max(ts)
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (order by ts) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by col order by ts) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by col, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

This includes the `col` value on each row, which seems very useful.

EDIT:

If you have the situation where you have duplicates timestamps in the data, you can use `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`.

Comment: thanks for your immediate response. In the above answer, if we order the "ts" the result may go wrong because in the dataset we have duplicate "ts" values for different dimension attributes. So we should not change the order of the time-series. We just need to extract the first and last value of "ts" when the constant value of the "col" column value changes.

Comment: Or if possible please send me the query that sets the flag value to the "ts" (0,1,2). For every first "col" value to be 1, last value to be 2 and the rest of the value to be 0.

Comment: @Sudha . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  Duplicates can introduce lots of problems into the data.  You should ask another question.  In particular, how do you know you don't have duplicates for a given dimension?

Comment: @Linoff yes, you're right. You've answered what I have asked for. Let me post another with more detail. Thanks.

Comment: @Sudha . . . Note my edit to the answer.  This probably does what you want,

Comment: @Linoff  the edit comment was very useful. The first answer worked very well for me when I use a "where" condition for each dimension attributes. Thanks a lot!